# Application of this device?

Tags: adc

I have something which can measure very high voltages at very high speed. These high voltage can be directly be given to input pins of this ADC without first converting to lower voltages.

---

Now here is a problem, **where can this be used?** I mean power electronics do not works in 10s of MHz range (I think so) and these days a high voltage probe can be used with oscilloscope to debug high voltage circuits. Because reducing the least count of this circuit to ~4mV (equivalent to 10 bit ADC) is impossible (as for now) so it can't be used for low voltage signals.

One application that I thought by myself is in mobile tower i.e. we directly connect this ADC to antenna and output is directly given to MCU. But I don't know if it is practical or not. I don't know how the circuits of mobile tower communication works? And where in that circuit would this ADC fits?

Any help/links is appreciated.

Thankyou for you time.

Comment: I don't think this question is relevant to this site. It sounds like an interesting invention, though, if it indeed works as you describe! But use for cellular antennas is almost certainly not going to happen; you need tens of gigasamples per second for that, and you claim about 0.1% of that.

Comment: @Hearth perhaps you could point out to which site I should ask this question would be great help!

Comment: Some questions come to mind. What kind of input circuit do you have that can handle a signal of 10,000 volts without either blowing up,  loading it down, and/or severly limiting the bandwidth due to stray capacitance? How do you achieve accuracy without a fixed reference voltage? If there is no external voltage what is powering the reference and what kind of signal is output?

Comment: @Barry - sounds like the invention of the resistor network to me :-)

Comment: @Barry it is just an example. In simulation I have gone up to 1kV. I have not done it practically!

Comment: Patent office? Start a company?

Comment: What are the tolerances when stacked up and complexity for 10kV?

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini - remember, passive components are not that easy in chipdesign. Are you sure your proposed ADC can be implemented better than existing topologies? If your design needs more die-area than a normal design I would call it academic but without chances in the market. Pherhaps you can combine your design with a traditional one, like folding and interpolating ADC's which are faster, more precise and smaller if done right...

Comment: Disclose anything here about it and it becomes unpatetable immediately.

Comment: @winny Yes and No... I have read patents which patented as main component a lookup table to translate adress from bus a to bus b. But it was renamed and obfuscated in such a "clever" maner, I neede 3 times reading the document until I recognized the mechanisms behind the words... And it is really hard to take down a patent once it was applied

Comment: @schnedan winny is pointing out that by describing the invention on here it is being put in the public domain. An idea that is in the public domain cannot be patented as it prior art.

Comment: @mhaselup I know - and suppose we all do... hopefully

Answer (score 3):

normally you need a patent lawer which knows rules and regulations, also they are skilled in how to write a valid patent. These documents are very formal and use unusal wording.

Also, international patents will cost you several thousand euro/dollar - just for the 10 biggest industrial regions or so.

So be sure you can get back your invest

Sometimes big universities hold patents, pay the fees. but dont expect to get heaps of money if you sell your invention to them. This is also the case if you do inventions as an employee

Comment: My university has a policy that If I file patent through them then they will be entitled to 40% of all profit from the patent. Although I haven't read exact mechanism. But I will certainly look  into this matter. Thank you

Comment: 60% for you sounds good to me... but you still need a way to make profit from it... if its a buyable product drop us a note :-) Good luck